# How to check if all JComponents are empty using Stream

Tags: java

I have:
JTextField, JPasswordField, JComboBox, DatePicker that I would like to check if they are all not empty.

For the moment I use:

```
boolean test(JTextField a, JPasswordField b, DatePicker c, JComboBox<Integer> d){
     
     ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<>();

     if(a==null || b==null || c==null || d==null) throw new Exception();
     
     text.add(a.getText());

     text.add(new String(b.getPassword()))
      
     String strDate = "";
     if (c.getDate()!= null) strDate = c.getDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
     text.add(strDate);

     String strMese = "";
     if (d.getSelectedItem() != null) strMese = d.getSelectedItem().toString();
     text.add(strMese);

     return text.stream().
            noneMatch(String::isEmpty));
}
```

How can I convert it using streams?
I would like a method like:

```
boolean test (List <?> component){
   return component.stream()...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you want is to use Optional together with Stream, for instance:

```
boolean test = Stream.of(
        Optional.ofNullable(a).map(JTextComponent::getText),
        Optional.ofNullable(b).map(JPasswordField::getPassword).map(String::new),
        Optional.ofNullable(d).map(JComboBox::getSelectedItem).map(Object::toString)
).allMatch(optional -> optional.isPresent() && !optional.get().isEmpty());
```

Comment: I would like to pass the fields without following an order and still have a correct result.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand but it's a stream, you can paste the fields with any order you want.

Comment: I would like a generic method where I can parameterize a varied list of JTextField, JPasswordField, JComboBox, DatePicker and DateTimePicker.  For example (JTextField a, JPasswordField b), (JTextField a, JTextField b).